# build a One Time Password authentication server

Tags: node.js, architecture, jwt, one-time-password

**Problem**

In our system we have:

- Two apps: a backoffice in reactjs and an app for user in react-native
- An API (with postgres db)
- Hubspot (user informations, phone number, etc.)

We want to add an authentication server to secure our user data and allow user to connect to the mobile app. That server would provide tokens and a link between Hubspot (that carries user informations) and the user in the API db. The db would store only hubspot user id and the api user id and some timestamp. We want to use a One Time Password using text messages.

The workflow would be something like:

- the user want to connect to the app (for the first time or not). The app is requesting a phone number.
- the phone number is sent to the auth server that checks if it exists in hubspot. If the user phone number exists but nothing yet in the database, that means we need to create a new user (in the auth server database AND in the api). If the user number exists and already in the database there is nothing to do. In both case, a token is generated and the user is able to connect (still need to understand how to do that). If nothing exist in hubspot, the user wouldn’t be able to authenticate in the app.

**Questions**

Am I going in the right direction? Creating an authentication server, is it a good idea or completely useless? Should we implement our logic directly in the API? The system is about medical information and data should be protected.

Concerning the OTP, what should we send to the user if the phone number actually exists? The auth token or a random string to require the actual token?

Answer (score 0):

> the phone number is sent to the auth server that checks if it exists
> in hubspot. If the user phone number exists but nothing yet in the
> database, that means we need to create a new user (in the auth server
> database AND in the api). If the user number exists and already in the
> database there is nothing to do. In both case, a token is generated
> and the user is able to connect (still need to understand how to do
> that). If nothing exist in hubspot, the user wouldn’t be able to
> authenticate in the app.

I do not think sending the phone number to the auth server is a good idea, instead you generate a code and save it on some backend server or some backend database and then text the user the same exact code. The reason for saving the code on the backend is to compare it to the one the user provides at some point in the future.

That is a unique identifying piece of information, not a phone number, peoples' phone numbers change all the time.

The user presumably receives the text message, that is the only reason we need the phone number for to send that text message and they can enter that code back into the application.

So the user sends us the correct code and that comes to the backend server. It's then compared on the server and if the user entered the correct code, send them some further identifying token, such as a JSON Web Token that identifies the user for future follow up requests.

This is what it means to be authenticated. Once the user successfully enters the token, we provide a user with a JSON Web Token to specifically identify them and say, hey this user did correctly enter a one time password, here is some identifying information on the user.